# How to ignore Self referencing loop detected In MVC View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

How can I prevent the "**Self-referencing loop detected**" error while serialising the object in  MVC View ?

```
 var fieldDependants = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
```

I added following configuration snip in **Global.asax** But still getting the same error.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
            .SerializerSettings
            .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Thanks

Comment: where in global.asax did you add this default.  You can also pass this value to the `serializeobject` call itself.

Comment: Your second code snippet configures the serializer used by MVC.  Your first code snippet does not use that serializer.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing where you placed the default in `Global.asax` you can ensure the setting is what you want by setting it explicitly with the `SerializeObject` call

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings With {.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore})  //VB


Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() {ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore})  //CS
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings` are only used by Web API.  They will not be picked up by a direct call to `SerializeObject` from an MVC view.  You could try setting the global `DefaultSettings` delegate on `JsonConvert`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```

If that doesn't work, you will need to pass the settings to `SerializeObject` directly as shown by @Steve in his answer.