# Charts in ASP NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

i want chart on Results Page. i have a class Results

```
    using System;

namespace PersonalArea.DAL.Models
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string PatientId { get; set; }

        public string GameName { get; set; }

        public string Time { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateExit { get; set; }

        public string DifficultLevel { get; set; }

        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In PatientController has a some method

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Results(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Patient patient = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id) as Patient;
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Result>> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName);
        return View(results);
    }
```

And in Results.cshtml have a some code:

```html
@model IQueryable<IGrouping<string, PersonalArea.DAL.Models.Result>>
@inject IJsonHelper Json;

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
        var datapoints = [];
        // build an array of objects
        $.each(model, function(index, item) {
    datapoints.push({ x: new Date(item.DateEnd), y: item.scores });


  window.onload = function () {
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "theme2",
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
     text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
    },
    subtitles: [
     { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
    ],
    data: [
    {
                        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                        dataPoints: datapoints
                    /*[
     { x: 10, y: 71 },
     { x: 20, y: 55 },
     { x: 30, y: 50 },
     { x: 40, y: 65 },
     { x: 50, y: 95 },
     { x: 60, y: 68 },
     { x: 70, y: 28 },
     { x: 80, y: 34 },
     { x: 90, y: 14 }
     ]*/
                                        //Uncomment below line to add data coming from the controller.
     //dataPoints: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
    }
    ]
   });
   chart.render();
  };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But system have error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'PersonalArea.DAL.Models.Result'. Path '[0][0].patient.results'.

Please, help my resolve this error

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `Newtonsoft.Json` configuration to ignore self-referecing loops like this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Or you can do this only in the serilization call:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize, Formatting.Indented, 
new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

You have these options:

- **ReferenceLoopHandling.Error** This is the default, will raise an error if a reference loop is detected. This is why you get an exception.
- **ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize** is useful if objects are nested but
  not indefinitely.
- **ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore** will not serialize an
  object if it is a child object of itself.

Comment: And where i can use it?

Comment: What’s happening in the code above is that in your DAL Model you have a self referencing loop, meaning some of your Parient properties is a Result object or something similar. When you serialize the Model in the view it throws an exception. In this code you should use the options I wrote above, meaning you should pass another parameter with the serialization options.

Comment: Another thing, a better approach than sending DAL objects to the View is using Viewmodels, where only the information the view needs is sent. You can use for example AutoMapper to do the job of converting the two model objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Results(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Patient patient = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id) as Patient;
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        list<Result> query = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).ToList();
ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
        return View(results);
```

View.chtml in

```
 <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            var test = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.test);
            var datapoints = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
                datapoints.push({ y: test[i].Score, x: test[i].ID, label: test[i].GameName });
            }
window.onload = function () {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "theme2",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title: {
                    text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
                },
                subtitles: [
                    { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
                ],
                data: [
                {
                        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                        dataPoints: datapoints
                    /*[
                    { x: 10, y: 71 },
                    { x: 20, y: 55 },
                    { x: 30, y: 50 },
                    { x: 40, y: 65 },
                    { x: 50, y: 95 },
                    { x: 60, y: 68 },
                    { x: 70, y: 28 },
                    { x: 80, y: 34 },
                    { x: 90, y: 14 }
                    ]*/
                                        //Uncomment below line to add data coming from the controller.
                    //dataPoints: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
        };

        }
```

Comment: I tryed write code in Contoller like this  List<Result> query = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).ToList(); but a have error "Cannot convert type from System.Linq.IGrouping to list". What can i do?

Comment: So this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49234780/9478131 i told about new problem, please, tell me, what can i do?